# FFmpeg forward iptv .ts remote stream returned (401 Unauthorized authorization failed)

Tags: ffmpeg, ubuntu-14.04, iptv

My problem is when i try to forward remote iptv channel .ts file from remote server using this command

Local Windows :

```
ffmpeg -i http://ip_tv_server.com:_port_/live/user/user/ts_file.ts -vcodec libx264 -vb 500k -vprofile baseline -level 2.1 -acodec aac -ab 64000 -ar 48000 -ac 2 -strict experimental -f flv rtmp://my_rtmp_server:1935/live/myStream -tune zerolatency
```

it works fine and start sending streaming to my server (red5-server) .

but when i use the same command in my linux vps (Ubuntu 14.04) i get this error from ffmpeg :

```
http://ip_tv_server.com:_port_/live/user/user/ts_file.ts: Server returned 401 Unauthorized (authorization failed)
```

do i need to use custom http headers ?

and why it's working on my local windows and not in vps (ubuntu 14.04-x64) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message generally means that you are trying to access something or perform some action on a server, and the server requires you to login or be be authorised to do it.

Generally this would be associated with a HTTP request and user name and password and/or a user session. The authorisation might even be as simple as checking a cookie on your local machine. This is one example of an authorisation which might work on one machine but not another.

The authorisation mechanism could also be much more involved or use some completely different logic - for example the server may have a GEO blocking mechanism and your local machine is on a network it considers to be ok while the VPS is not.

There server may even have a mechanism to limit concurrent devices or concurrent streams and accessing the same stream from two devices could trigger this.